# multiple parameters nusoap

Tags: web-services, parameters, arguments, nusoap

I have a web service that I am using that when I use a method, I can pass one parameter. I am trying to figure out how to pass multiple if it is possible. So, for example:

I have one table that has a list of students in a school. In this table the columns are:

```
STUDENT_NAME     | STUDENT_ID   |    STUDENT_GRADE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Smith       | 0123456      | 1st Grade
Mike Johnson     | 8564377      | 1st Grade
Tori Mackrill    | 0123456      | 2nd Grade
Beth Gridly      | 8564377      | 3rd Grade
```

So I would like to be able to set a parameter value to return all students that are either in 1st or 3rd grade. Right now, I can easily return just 1 grade, but when I set the argument to be for two parameters separated by a comma, it will not work. Here is an an example of what I have so far for the one parameter.

```
function getStudents($Grade)
   {
       $CI =& get_instance();
       $CI->load->model("gradelevel");

       $where = array('STUDENT_GRADE'=>$grade);
       $result = $CI->gradelevel->getStudents($where); 
       $Student = $result->row_array();

       return  $Student;
    }

$this->nusoap_server->register('getStudents',
        array ('Grade' => "xsd:string"),           // input parameters
        array("return"=>"tns:Grades"),             // output parameters
        'urn:nuserver',                            // namespace
        'urn:nuserver#getStudents',                // SOAPAction
        'rpc',                                     // style
        'encoded',                                 // use
        'Returns a list of students');
```

What do I need to add or change to have it accept more than one grade choice?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
function getStudents($Grade,$Grade2,$Grade3)
 {
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->model("gradelevel");

   $where = array('STUDENT_GRADE'=>$grade);
   $result = $CI->gradelevel->getStudents($where); 
   $Student = $result->row_array();

   return  $Student;
  }

$this->nusoap_server->register('getStudents',
    array ('Grade' => "xsd:string", 'Grade2' => "xsd:string", 'Grade3' => "xsd:string"),           // input parameters
    array("return"=>"tns:Grades"),             // output parameters
    'urn:nuserver',                            // namespace
    'urn:nuserver#getStudents',                // SOAPAction
    'rpc',                                     // style
    'encoded',                                 // use
    'Returns a list of students');
```